# Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium

My goal is to make selenium input text into a text field, I can't get it to work, and it's not giving any output, so I have no clue where it's going wrong.

```
fname = driver.find_element_by_name("fname")
fname.send_keys("Johnathon")
lname = driver.find_element_by_name("lname")
lname.send_keys("Morris")
email = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email.send_keys("JohnMorris@gmail.com")
email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

That's the code of my script.

```
<input type="text" name="fname" class="styles_input__TJVdS styles_themeLight__1SJ2R styles_textInput__3dAOE" placeholder="First Name" spellcheck="false" value="">

<input type="text" name="lname" class="styles_input__TJVdS styles_themeLight__1SJ2R styles_textInput__3dAOE" placeholder="Last Name" spellcheck="false" value="">

<input autocapitalize="off" type="text" name="email" class="styles_input__TJVdS styles_themeLight__1SJ2R styles_textInput__3dAOE" placeholder="Email" inputmode="email" spellcheck="false" value="">
```

That's the HTML code for the site, the script is finding the elements by the name, which seems to be correct, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: all the three elements that you showed has the same classes, so you'll probably have to find another way of differentiating them

Comment: you can define the elements by name, and class name, and I defined them by the name, so shouldn't the class name have nothing to do with it?

Comment: can you add a `print` statement to make sure that the variables aren't null?